# Selecting Deployment target in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, realm, cloudkit

I have an iOS application that I would like to put in the AppStore. I am however lost in the aspect of development target. I do not know if I have to set the deployment target as 11.0 or 10.0. Most of the code works good with 10.x. I would like to know if it's a good practise to set the deployment target to lower version.

Answer (score 5):

Its good to use one version less than the one currently in Market. Of course if you have larger audience using you app and having lower version of iOS on their iPhones, you can choose much lower version as deployment target.

Answer (score 4):

You can set it based on your choice, if you would like to cover all the users using iOS devices then you can set deployment target to 10.x OR as per the latest analytical data from the Apple, there are only 7% devices using iOS 10.x or lower, so you can ignore them too and can set deployment target to 11.x and above.

Refer here: [Analytics of iOS Users](https://developer.apple.com/support/app-store/)